# Menu control in silverlight 4 similar to WPF Menu

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want a **menu control for my silverlight 4.0 application**.
The functionality should be similar to a WPF menu control,
Can you suggest me the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

http://silverlightpopupmenu.codeplex.com/

http://slmenu.codeplex.com/

http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/menu_(popup).aspx

You could also try paid components such as

http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/silverlight/menu/

http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/menu.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other ones you might want to try:

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com/

http://www.viblend.com/products/net/silverlight/controls/silverlight_menu_control.aspx